# Python combinactions via list comprehension with variable input array

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, combinations, python-itertools

## Dynamic list comprehension

### Solution with fixed sized list

Let's say I have a list `array=['abc','def','ghi']` and I want to compute all the different combinations i.e. `comb=['adg','adh','adi','bdg',...]` **without** using   [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

This is possible e.g. via `result = [(x+y+z) for x in pos[0] for y in pos[1] for z in pos[2]]`.

### Problem with variable list size

How to rewrite the list comprehension with variable length array list e.g. `result= [(a+b+c+...) for a in pos[0] for ... for z in pos[-1]`?

Comment: "Without using ..." *why*? Anyway, research `zip`

Comment: Use `itertools.product`.

Comment: @DeepSpace I don't see how `zip` is helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually looking for the product of these strings (not a combination per se).

This will be a convoluted list comprehension but here goes:

```
L=['abc','def','ghi']

R = [ "".join(s[i//b%len(s)] for s,b in zip(L,base))
      for base in [[1]] if [base.extend(base[-1]*len(s) for s in L)]
      for i in range(base[-1])]

print(R)
['adg', 'bdg', 'cdg', 'aeg', 'beg', 'ceg', 'afg', 'bfg', 'cfg',
 'adh', 'bdh', 'cdh', 'aeh', 'beh', 'ceh', 'afh', 'bfh', 'cfh', 
 'adi', 'bdi', 'cdi', 'aei', 'bei', 'cei', 'afi', 'bfi', 'cfi']
```

The `for base ...` part is a trick to get an internal list of multipliers for the unranked result while it is sequentially accessed using an index for 0 to the product of string lengths (i).

If you want the result in string order, you can write it  like this:

```
R = [ "".join(s[i//b%len(s)] for s,b in zip(L,base[1:]))
      for base in [[1]] if [base.insert(0,base[0]*len(s)) for s in L[::-1]]
      for i in range(base[0])]

print(R)
['adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei', 'afg', 'afh', 'afi', 
 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei', 'bfg', 'bfh', 'bfi',
 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei', 'cfg', 'cfh', 'cfi']
```

This gives the same result as: `["".join(p) for p in itertools.product(*L)]` albeit not as efficiently.